# Custom Paper Size Printing Small Contents in Crystal Report C#

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I have created a custom paper size and assigned it to my crystal report file. It's working fine when I am opening this file in Crystal Report but when I am printing it using `PrintToPrinter` all contents get shrink and printing in a very small size. I can't understand what I am doing wrong here.
My customer size is 4.72 (H) x 6.3 (V)
Here is my code

```
using (ReportDocument rptDc = new ReportDocument())
                        {
                            using (DataSet HospDataSet = new HospitalDataSet())
                            {
                                DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
                                Dt.Columns.Add("Sr", typeof(int));
                                Dt.Columns.Add("Query", typeof(string));
                                Dt.Rows.Add(1, "Select * from ME_ProductSale where Id = " + SetId);
                                Dt.Rows.Add(2, "Select * from ME_ProductSale_Detail where IdFk = " + SetId + " Order by Sr");
                                Dt.Rows.Add(3, "Select * from ME_Identity");
                                using (DataSet Ds = GetPrintDetails(Dt, Con))
                                {
                                    HospDataSet.Tables["ME_ProductSale"].Merge(Ds.Tables[0]);
                                    HospDataSet.Tables["ME_ProductSale_Detail"].Merge(Ds.Tables[1]);
                                    HospDataSet.Tables["ME_Identity"].Merge(Ds.Tables[2]);
                                    ReportPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Reports_ME\\rptProductSale.rpt";
                                    rptDc.Load(ReportPath);
                                    rptDc.SetDataSource(HospDataSet);                                    
                                    rptDc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = Connections.GetGlobalSettingsME.Rows[0]["PrinterName"].ToString();                                    
                                    rptDc.PrintToPrinter(SetPrintCopies, false, 0, 0);                                     
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: 4.72 (H) x 6.3 (V) on A4 size paper will be small.

Comment: If you go into the Page Setup for your crystal report there is a section called Printer Options.  Have you tried checking the check box here that is labeled "No Printer (optimize for screen display)?